# Fishpig Magento Extension: Homepage and sidebar widgets not working

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

When I add widgets to my "First Front Page Widget Area" nothing appears on my homepage.

I am using WordPress template Twenty Twelve. I created a "home" page and assigned it to be a "Front Page Template". I also customized the template to show the static page "home".  I assigned the recent posts to show on homepage as a tests and nothing shows, just the page title (Home).

I tried changing my file `Fishpig_Wordpress.xml` (under `app/etc/modules/`) to `Fishpig_Wordpress.xml.old`, but this made WordPress inaccessible (404 error), so I changed the name back to `Fishpig_Wordpress.xml`.

Lastly, I tried updating the the extension to the latest version 3.0.3.8 (stable) and still the widgets are not showing.

Anybody knows what else I can do or what might be preventing my widgets from working?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the app/etc/modules/Fishpig_Wordpress.xml file is the bootstrap file for this extension. This file instructs Magento where the code lives for this file. Deleting - or renaming - this file will not fix any issues but will disable the module (you may need a cache refresh for this change to be acted on).

With the latest version of the extension, widgets should work in the left or right columns of your Magento template. To ensure this, happens, enable the Twenty Twelve theme (which you have done) and ensure you are using the latest version of wordpress.xml. Check your custom theme's layout folder for wordpress.xml and rename it wordpress.xml.old, as this will force Magento to use the latest version of the file in base/default. After doing this, you will need to refresh your layout XML cache.

Next, ensure that you actually have some widgets enabled. To test this, enable a default widget like the Search widget or the Recent Posts.

The above is generic advice for people who can't get widgets to display. Your situation is slightly different as it sounds like widgets work for you, just not on your custom homepage. If this is correct, check that your custom WP page is using a template that has a sidebar column. You can do this by checking the HTML source. Alternatively, reply to this answer with your URL and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @BenT.  The URL to my blog is this: [link](http://www.aicmillworks.com/blog)

Comment: I went to my template's layout folder and found the file wordpress.xml then renamed it wordpress.xml.old, then I went to the cache management in Magento and refreshed.  This made my blog disappear, even the link on my navigation.

Comment: This may mean that you have copied the wordpress.xml from base/default to your custom theme. Please contact me using the form on http://fishpig.co.uk/contact-us/ as I will have to to take a look at your situation first hand to resolve this issue.